# The compiler is not recognizing my input for .getPoint

Tags: java, keylistener, keyevent

We areto create a plane and have its speed increase 5mph every time the user inputs the up arrow key and decrease 9mph when hitting the down key. It is supposed it report this back to the user in output box whenever whichever action is completed. How do I set it up so that the keylistener will tell the user that they have pressed the up key? Im still working on this so sorry if it is messy.

```
  private class PolygonPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, KeyListener
  {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event){}   //unused event
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event){}   //unused event
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event){} 
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event){}
    //public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event){}


  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
    Integer planespeed=event.getKeyCode();

    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
      //Not gonna use this.
    }
    if (event.getKeyCode() == 39)//KeyEvent.VK_LEFT
    {

      System.out.print("This key is up");
    }
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
      System.out.print("This key has been pressed");
      //speed=planespeed+5;
    }
     if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
      //speed=planespeed-9;
    }
     repaint();
  }
```

Comment: have you imported the correct `MouseEvent` class?

Comment: I think so, it is this right? import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

Comment: have you add your listener instance to your main panel? (something like mainapp.addKeyListener(new PolygonPanel()))

Answer (score 0):

A frame doesn't detect keybaord input if it is not focused on. Therefore, in order to retrieve keyboard input of any kind, you would have to set your frame to be focusable, using a line such as `setFocusable(true);` in your constructor. You might also have to add a line such as `addKeyListener(new PolygonPanel());` so the listener is registered at all.

Comment: This. This is exactly what i needed. Thank you so much!